# WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.default.collection is not a function while building react.js app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redux

I'm making a webapp using react.js and firebase but it's showing this error, i know this is because of v9 of firebase module does not contain db. This is my code:

```
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [detailData, setDetailData] = useState({});

  var docRef = db.collection("movies").doc(id);

  useEffect(() => {
    docRef.get().then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          setDetailData(doc.data());
        } else {
          console.log("no such document in firebase");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
  }, [id]);
```

and my firebase file contains:

```
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { auth, provider, storage };
export default db;
```

Comment: `db.collection("movies").doc(id)` is older namespaced syntax. The new Modular syntax of the same would be `doc(db, "movies", id)`. Checkout the linked answer and the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) for more information.

Comment: It's still not working, now its shows **docRef.get is not a function**. Can you please help out with this.